# sending test mails not working in simplenews

Tags: 7, emails

Regular emails works as expected, but i cannot use test ones. When i go to `/admin/config/services/simplenews/setting`s i choose **Send one test newsletter to the test address** then pressing save button, but i am not getting any test emails - what's wrong?

Regular emails to real users works well, but not test emails. Or i am doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: any error log at admin/reports/dtblog?

Comment: not a single error regarding sending emails with simplenews

Comment: please check if [this link](https://drupal.org/node/369754) helps you in debugging the mail issue.

Comment: I don't have any problems listed in this page and i have read it already before creating this topic. The only problem i am experiencing is - sending test emails is not working. Or i am doing wrong? Do you have manual on how to send test mails? because in readme.txt nothing said about that

Comment: I am not sure if it will help you, still here is a descriptive manual in [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/desk02/dug-simplenews-6192093) for simplenews.

Comment: Thanks, but no success. Do you have any idea how to send test email?